# Rename subset of variables in data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set that I would wish to split into multiple data sets for further analysis, based on three variables. The data set looks like this:

```
tooth   side    site    probe1  probe2
11  facial  mesial  2   2
12  lingual distal  4   1
13  lingual mesial  1   9
```

I hereby would wish to subset the data into 3 datsets based on the tooth, side and site.

I have managed to write a function that does this as follows, however I would wish to assign names to each individual data set.

```
each<- function(x){

tooth<-unique(x$tooth)

side<-unique(x$side)

site<-unique(x$site)

   for i in 1:length(tooth){

   for j in 1:length(side){

for k in 1:length(site){

subset(x,tooth==tooth[i] & side==side[j], & site==site[k]))

}

}}}
```

Unfortunately

Comment: It seems, you missed writing the question here

Comment: Before you fill your workspace with subsets of your data frame, you should be aware of that there are several excellent tools for analysing grouped data in `base` R (e.g. `by`, `aggregate`, `ave`), as well as in packages such as `data.table`, `ddply`, `dplyr`. Search SO for loads of nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `split`:

```
split(x, list(x$tooth, x$side, x$site))
```

where `x` is your original dataframe.

Comment: thanks for that. my challenge is how do i assign a name to each of the datasets?

Comment: @user3354564 Why do you need to name them?

Comment: basically am trying to write a package to classify disease in epidemiology of gum disease. This will involve a logical argument for each tooth/side/site, for two measurements(probing depth and recession). My approach is to subset each of the measurements into the individual datasets, then apply the logical arguments as independent datasets.

Comment: You probably don't need to have named dataframes for that purpose. You can just apply the classification function to every dataframe in the list that comes out of `split` using `lapply`.